# How to pass one field value in an object to an other object? (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lookup

I have an object in which i enter an email and I have an other object in which  I want that email to display by default without having to rewrite it (same email for same person) .
as you can see in the picture.

[image]

[image]

```
   <lightning-input-field   field-name='Candidat__c' onchange={handleCandidatChange}   > </lightning-input-field>
   <lightning-input-field   field-name='Email_de_Candidat__c' value='Candidat__r.Email' onchange={handleEmailChange}> </lightning-input-field>
```

---

```
handleEmailChange(event) {
this.email = event.target.value;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Please don't use a screenshot for code. Copy-paste the code and use the `{}` button in the editor for formatting.

Comment: okay thank you i will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class ContactAccessor {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Contact fetchContact(String conId){
        return [SELECT Id,Name,Email FROM Contact WHERE ID=:conId];
    }
}
```

**HTML Form**

```
<template>

    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="dsrprash__Expense__c">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="dsrprash__Candidat__c" onchange={handleCandidatChange}></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="dsrprash__Email_de_Candidat__c" value={candidateEmail} data-my-id="cand-email"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>

</template>
```

**JS Code**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import fetchContactDetails from '@salesforce/apex/ContactAccessor.fetchContact';

export default class ContactEmail extends LightningElement {

    candidateEmail; //this property is binded with the "Email de Candidat" 

    handleCandidatChange(event){
        console.log('selected candidate = '+event.target.value);
        let candidateId =  event.target.value; //this contains the user selected Candidat's Id

        //getting reference of the HTML element of "Email de Candidat"
        let canEmailRef = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-field[data-my-id=cand-email]');
        if(candidateId && canEmailRef){
            //invoking apex method to fetch the selected Candidat Details...
            fetchContactDetails({conId:candidateId})
            .then( result => {
                console.log(' ## result from the apex method = '+JSON.stringify(result));
                this.candidateEmail = result.Email;
            })
            .catch( error => {
                //handle error...
                alert(' something went wrong in apex call..');
            });           
        }
        else{
            console.log(' cannot find the Candidat Email field ref in DOM...');
        }
    }
}
```

*onchange event is added on Candidat field and calling handleCandidatChange method. Then it will fetch the details of the selected candidate and updates the email in the "Email de Candidat" field value attribute*

Hoping that, this will be helpful!

Comment: thanks for the answer . I will try it right now but first i'd like to know how to bring data from two different objects please ! still a begineer

Comment: Could you help me in understanding the overall requirement? Please provide more details.

Comment: Okay Ofc ! I have two objets( Contact and Interviews) I have a list of contacts in which they have emails ; I want to be able when I create a new interview , i enter the name of a contact and his email appears (i can't do this)  Im now obliged to rewrite the same email which exists in the object contact

Comment: Lets say, the relationship field on Interview object to Contact is Contact__c. Then we can create a new formula field on Interview object which will pull up the email from the related record. Formula: Contact__r.Email

I guess this will work right?

Comment: I've tried that but the fact that I need an email so i can send an email to the contact who have an interview ! I need type email

Comment: Also I have two emails( the contact and the person interviewing) and both of them are CONTACT make things more complicated

Comment: By sending email i meant email alert and to both the contact and the person interviewing

Comment: Correct me if my understanding is wrong,
From above(question screenshot) you want to pre-populate the email of the "Candidat" selected into "Email de Candidat"

And you are doing it lwc.

Comment: Yes thats true    you are right

Comment: I will give you the code snippet to achieve the above. please give me sometime

Comment: Take your time and thank you so much

Comment: I have provided the code in the answer. Can you try that and let me know if you have issues.